# ADFS proxy connect to wrong ADFS

Tags: adfs

I configured web application proxy on Windows Server 2012 and I noticed that when user makes request then gets exception:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

On wap server in event viewer I found the below exception. I don't know why but ip specified inside exception is wrong - how is this resolved?

> Unable to retrieve proxy configuration data from the Federation Service.
>
> Additional Data
>
> Trust Certificate Thumbprint: 
>   81E6CF17894A85B134D12DBEDE0E07CDC2F57FD3
>
> Status Code:
>
> Exception details:  System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Proxy.StsConfigurationProvider.GetStsProxyConfiguration()

Comment: You'll need to look around more before you ask for help. Because right now it just looks like your adfs proxy is configured wrong. You can review the [adfs installation blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/04/28/how-to-install-adfs-2012-r2-for-office-365_1320_part-2.aspx) for confiugration steps. Also you might want to check what the purpose is of the server to which it is trying to respond.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration of ADFS Proxy was wrong. Firstly I couldn't find certificate with thumbprint specified in the exception (81E6CF17894A85B134D12DBEDE0E07CDC2F57FD3). Secondly I couldn't change proxy address. I found help in this [great article (Things that don’t update when changing an AD FS URL in Windows Server 2012 R2)](http://tristanwatkins.com/changing-adfs-url-windows-server-2012-r2/) information that:

> I’ve completely un/re-installed the Web Application Proxy, but the Web
>   Application Proxy configuration data that AD FS holds has never been
>   updated through any of these changes, even after uninstalling and
>   reinstalling it.

So I executed this command and it works.

```
Install-WebApplicationProxy -CertificateThumbprint "B2CorrectThumbprint " -FederationServiceName "federation_service_name"
```